# C++ stdin occasionally garbled

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdin

I've been experiencing a strange occasionally occurring bug for the last few days.

I have a console application that also displays a window opened with SDL for graphical output continuously running three threads. The main thread runs the event loop, and processes the console input. The second thread uses `std::cin.getline` to get the console input. This second thread, however, is also responsible for outputting logging information, which can be produced when the user clicks somewhere on the SDL window.

These log messages are sent to a mutex-protected `stringstream` regularly checked by thread 2. If there are log messages it deletes the prompt, outputs them and then prints a new prompt. Due to this it can't afford to block on `getline`, so this thread spawns the third thread that `peek`s `cin` and signals via an `atomic` when there's data to be got from the input stream, at which point `getline` is called and the input is passed to the logic on the main thread.

Here's the bit I haven't quite worked out, about 1 in 30 of these fails since the program doesn't receive exactly the same input as was typed into the terminal. You can see what I mean in the images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNcdw.jpg), the first line is what was type and the second is the Lua stacktrace due to receiving different (incorrect) input.

This occurs whether I use `rlwrap` or not. Is this due to `peek` and `getline` hitting the input stream at the same time? (This is possible as the `peek` loop just looks like:

```
while(!exitRequested_)
{
  if (std::cin.peek())
    inputAvailable_ = true; // this is atomic

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}
```

Any thoughts? I looked at curses quickly, but it looks like quite a lot of effort to use. I've never heard of get line garbling stuff before. But I also printed every string that was received for a while and they matched what Lua is reporting.

Comment: It does seem possible that `peek` interferes with `getline`. I'm not sure what the C++ standard says regarding thread-safety of IO streams, but even if it should be thread-safe there is the possibility of a bug in the library. Would it be possible to use a two-way communication between the _peeking_ thread and the thread that actually does input? I.e. the peeking thread sets `inputAvailable` and only resumes peeking once it has been cleared again by the other thread (after it has called `getline`). This might be worth a try, anyway.

Comment: @davmac This seems like it might have fixed it, I can't be conclusive yet due to the bug often just not showing up for ages (nature of threaded bugs I suppose). But I tried quite a lines (100+) with no errors which is looking promising. I don't really know why I didn't think of that before. I initially had a pair of bools doing that work (one needed to be true and one false), terrible idea - they kept getting desynchronised leaving the program without input, so I took that lock away and I think that's when this problem appeared. So maybe just the one will do the trick.

Comment: Concurrent accesses to the same stream object are explicitly prohibited.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks, it's good to know that explicitly, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Have you considered splitting the responsibilities of displaying to the console and reading from standard input into separate threads? You could even keep roughly the same design by having the new thread simply copy lines into a buffer, say `deque<string>`, so the only change to your existing thread is to replace reads from `cin` with queries the buffer to see if there is content. (and you could even use timed waits on a condition variable rather than sleeping and polling, so as to have better response times)

Comment: @Hurkyl That's roughly part of the process I went through getting here. If you want to print a prompt and also out put log messages, the only way I could see of doing it was to check for messages, if there are some, remove the prompt ('\b' the right amount), then print the messages before reprinting the prompt. This is what thread1 (0-indexed) spends its time doing. Thread2 informs thread1 that the user has entered something it can take who reads it and passes it on thread0, who then processes it. I admit, thread0 could just read the data when thread2 announces its existence - 1/2

Comment: the system just kind of grew like this. In that case, thread2 would peek, thread1 would print prompt and output, while thread0 runs its event loop and grabs the input. Now, it would also be possible to spawn a fourth thread that waits on a condition set by the peek thread to grab the line and pass it to main thread, I don't beleve this is better than the current solution and worse than moving getline to thread0 as a mutex can then disappear from the system. Thread2 spends most of its time blocked on peek and thread1 could then be moved to a condition, but I don't believe there's much to gain.

Comment: @Goobley: Making thread2 do the read rather than peeking would probably make things simpler.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. Tunnel vision here I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @davmac suggested, `peek` appears to have been interfering with `getline`. My assumption would be that this is linked to `peek` taking a character and then putting it back at the same time as `getline` takes the buffer.

Whatever the underlying cause of the issue is, I am >98% sure that the problem has been fixed by implementing the fix davmac suggested.
In several hours of use I have had no issues.

Moral, don't concurrently access `cin`, even if one of the functions doesn't modify the stream.

(Note, the above happened on both g++ and clang++ so I assume that it's just linked to the way the `std` library is frequently implemented).

As @DavidSchwartz pointed out, concurrent access to streams is explicitly prohibited, so that clearly explains why the fix works.